Отправка логов из promtail в loki
Провожу настройку отправки логов контейнеров docker в grafana/loki, с помощью promtail.
У меня есть два сервера, на первом:

docker c контейнерами
promtail

на втором:

grafana
loki

Цель: отправлять логи контейнеров docker в loki, а так же кастомные файлы логов.
все сервисы развернулись отлично, логи контейнеров пишутся в loki моментально, но кастомные файлы .log не отражаются в loki, хотя в логах контейнера promtail есть:

level=info ts=2024-05-15T13:38:12.147950408Z caller=filetargetmanager.go:361 msg="Adding target" key="/opt/test/*/*log:{host="test.ru", job="ldmcoreservices"}"

далее я открываю таргеты в promtail, здесь таргет для логов контейнеров docker  - работает ок

но интересующий таргер не реди

вот мой конфиг для promtail
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:

  - job_name: ldmcoreservices
    static_configs:
    - targets:
        - localhost
      labels:
        job: ldmcoreservices
        host: test.ru
        __path__: /opt/test/*/*log
    
  - job_name: containers
    static_configs:
    - targets:
        - localhost
      labels:
        job: containerlogs
        host: test.ru
        __path__: /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*log

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем я ошибаюсь, почему логи для таргета ldmcoreservices не отправляются в loki?
